# Попап со скроллом в Safari - проблемы в вёрстке для мобильной версии

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, прокрутка, safari

Подскажите, пжл., решение такой проблемки на версия safari для дэсктопа: 11.0.1, и айфона7:
при клике на кнопку, обычным jquery кодом, открывается попап с бэкграундом на :after-e. - При первом движении скролла бэкграйнд становится невидимым и текст в модальном окне тоже невидим, сам попап с белым бэкграундом виден как пустое белое поле, - все *невидимые* элементы есть на своих местах, но они "невидимы"!  - при последующих попытках проскроллить экран(иногда прокручиваю вверх до упора, иногда при просто последующем событии скролла) - всё отображается: и бэкграунд и текст попапа и больше не "пропадает", но такое повторяется при всех последующих "открытиях" попапа. Если в инспекторе я любой элемент *касаюсь* в попытке изменить стиль - сразу на экране отображается всё в рабочем состоянии: т.е. и бэкграунд и текст в попапе. (Внутри попапа есть вертикальный скролл)
Проблема в том, что при именно первом событии скролла становиться *невидим* бэкграунд на :after-e (position:fixed) и текст в попапе (попап тоже на position:fixed), но сам попап с белам бэкграундом и с *невидимым* текстом виден (.
Код для открытия/закрытия попапа: `

```
$(".open-desc").click(function(){
            $('.product-description-tab-content-mob, .close-desc').show('300');
            $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden !important');
        });
        $(".close-desc").click(function(){
            $(this).hide('300');
            $('.product-description-tab-content-mob').hide('300');
            $('body').css('overflow', 'unset');
        });
```

`Бэкграунд:`

```
.product-description-tab-content-mob:after {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  }
```

`Попап:`

```
.product-description-tab-content-mob {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 5%;
    top: 15%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 75%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 160000001;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

`

Comment: добавьте ваш [mcve]

Comment: Для открытия/закрытия попап: 
`$(".open-desc").click(function(){
            $('.product-description-tab-content-mob, .close-desc').show('300');
        });
        $(".close-desc").click(function(){
            $(this).hide('300');
            $('.product-description-tab-content-mob').hide('300');
        });`
Бэкграунд попапа: `.product-description-tab-content-mob:after {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  }`

Comment: Сам попап: `.product-description-tab-content-mob {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 5%;
    top: 15%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 75%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 160000001;
    padding: 0;
  }`

Comment: нажмите кнопку редактировать, в редакторе нажмите кнопку фрагмент кода, вставьте код туда

Comment: код должен быть понятным и воспроизводимым

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari плохо реагирует на псевдоэлементы(after,before), в моём случае пришлось переделать бэкграунд и уйти от :after-а.